# Solving ugly syntax for getter in js

Tags: javascript, closures

Let's take this object:

```
var person = {
    _name: "John",
    name: function() {return _name}
}
```

In GUI,

```
myTextBox.value = person.name()
```

will return

```
"John"
```

But

```
myTextBox.value = person.name
```

will return

```
function() {return _name}
```

How can I force both syntax to return `"John"`? Could I use a closure ([question I asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753382/why-use-closure-in-that-simple-case)) somehow here?

Comment: You *could* use an ugly hack, namely `func.toString = func` and use the `==` operator when comparing strings... I don't advise it, though.

Comment: seems interesting but could you detail in asnwer thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**You can't!**

- You can't override javascript operators or keywords.
- **you really can't have one operator\keyword that does two different things in the same context!**

Comment: this is untrue with getters in es5, but you're right that's it's probably not needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you support only modern browsers you can use a [ES5 Getters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/07/transitioning-existing-code-to-the-es5-getter-setter-apis.aspx), but in general this is JavaScript, why are you trying to make it complicated?

Your alternatives are:

1. make a rule that you have to use the function to access the variable (yuck)
2. don't worry about it.

I'd go for #2.

I think you're getting confused with this syntax here, but actually it has the same problem as you do now:

```
function Person(name) {
 this._name = name;   
}
Person.prototype.name = function(name) {
  if (name) this._name = name;
  return this._name;
}
var j = new Person("Jay");
j.name() // "Jay"
j.name("Thomas"); // I can set the value as well
j.name() // "Thomas"
```

It seems like you're trying to create *real* private variables, which are possible, but probably not that helpful.

```
function Person(name) {
  var myName = name; // private
  this.name = function() {
    return myName;
  }
}
var j = new Person("Jay");
j.name(); // still had to use perens
```

Finally because yours is just a simple object, we can do this. Not sure why you'd want to though:

```
var person = {};
(function(name) {
  var myName = name; // myName and name, both private, but not helpful
  person = {
    name = myName
  }
}("Jay"))
person.name // "Jay"
```

Comment: Great article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/07/transitioning-existing-code-to-the-es5-getter-setter-apis.aspx thanks

Comment: Will try your second syntax (by the way my getter may be more complex than that but anyhow even in that simple case I just want to learn if it's possible :)). If it does work it will be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, had a play and it looks like this is "possible" (At least in chrome) but its a bit of a dirty hack.

```
var person = {
   _name: "John",
   name: function() {return this._name;},
}
person.name.toString = function(){ return person._name; }
```

Which will result in both person.name and person.name() returning "John".